# FileNotFoundException when submitting to Spark Cluster

Tags: scala, cluster-computing, apache-spark, filenotfoundexception

I've created a small application using Apache Spark, when I run the application locally everything runs fine. But when I submit it to a 6-node cluster I get a FileNotFoundException, because he can't find the input file.

This is my tiny application.

```scala
def main (args: Array[String]) {
  val sparkContext = new SparkContext(new SparkConf())
  val tweets = sparkContext.textFile(args(0))

  tweets.map { line => (line, LanguageDetector.create().detect(line)) }
     .saveAsTextFile("/data/detected")
}
```

I submit the application with the following command:

```
/opt/spark-1.0.2-bin-hadoop2/bin/spark-submit --class YarnTest --master spark://luthor-v1:7077 lang_detect.jar twitter_data
```

After the submit I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0.0:1 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Exception failure in TID 6 on host luthor-v5: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/opt/bb/twitter_data does not exist
```

The file is there for sure, the jar and the file are in the same directory and it can resolve the full path.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried typing the file extension too? It could be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Try giving full path to the input file (ex: /root/twitter_data). Is it present on all the workers?

Comment: @DanOsipov No, the file isn't present on all worker nodes. It only resides on the master node. I'm guessing that is my problem. I could store my file on an HDFS cluster as suggested below.

Comment: I am having same problem as OP. I have copied the file to HDFS, but still same error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`spark-submit` assumes that the `jar` is residing in the current working directory and the file mentioned is in the hdfs. Copy your file `twitter_data` from the local file system to hdfs like this:

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal twitter_data /twitter_data
```

It will copy the file into `/` directory of hdfs. Now run the command:

```
spark-submit --class YarnTest --master spark://luthor-v1:7077 lang_detect.jar /twitter_data
```

Comment: I am having same problem as OP. I have copied the file to HDFS, but still same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: is there a way to make the Spark context do that? I don't want to manually put the file into HDFS. Can't it do it by itself

Comment: @salvob see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27299923/how-to-load-local-file-in-sc-textfile-instead-of-hdfs) question.

Answer (score 0):

The Hadoop configuration directory "spark-env.sh" is probably not ok. Please check it. It should be: "your_hadoop_dir **/etc/hadoop/** "