# How to load local file in sc.textFile, instead of HDFS

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm following the great [spark tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWeWViFCzzg)

so i'm trying at 46m:00s to load the `README.md` but fail to what i'm doing is this:

```
$ sudo docker run -i -t -h sandbox sequenceiq/spark:1.1.0 /etc/bootstrap.sh -bash
bash-4.1# cd /usr/local/spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4
bash-4.1# ls README.md
README.md
bash-4.1# ./bin/spark-shell
scala> val f = sc.textFile("README.md")
14/12/04 12:11:14 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(164073) called with curMem=0, maxMem=278302556
14/12/04 12:11:14 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 160.2 KB, free 265.3 MB)
f: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = README.md MappedRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:12
scala> val wc = f.flatMap(l => l.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://sandbox:9000/user/root/README.md
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:285)
```

how can I load that `README.md`?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Try explicitly specify `sc.textFile("file:///path to the file/")`. The error occurs when Hadoop environment is set.

SparkContext.textFile internally calls `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits`, which in turn uses `org.apache.hadoop.fs.getDefaultUri` if schema is absent. This method reads "fs.defaultFS" parameter of Hadoop conf. If you set HADOOP_CONF_DIR environment variable, the parameter is usually set as "hdfs://..."; otherwise "file://".

Comment: Do you happen to know how to do this with Java? I don't see a method.  Finding it very frustrating that there's not an easy way to give a path to load a file from a simple file system .

Comment: answering myself.  There is a --file switch that you pass with the spark-submit.  So, the file path can be hard coded or however your config is setup for the app, but you also signal that path . when you submit so that the executors can see the path.

Comment: When I specify the path on Windows, why `"file:///C:\\Xiang\\inputfile` and `"file:////C:\\Xiang\\inputfile` both works, while `"file://C:\\Xiang\\inputfile` does not work in the Java code. How about on linux? Should the prefix be `file:///` (three slash), or `file:////` (four slash)? Does `file:////` also work on linux?

Comment: I checked in the source code, it is `static final URI NAME = URI.create("file:///");`, so I suppose that it should be hard-coded as `file:///` (three slash) as the prefix. But I still do not understand why  `file:////` (four slash) also works.

Comment: @YuXiang Do you want to add a link to the line of the source code (in GitHub)?

Comment: @suztomo, it is here: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.4/api/src-html/org/apache/hadoop/fs/RawLocalFileSystem.html

Comment: @suztomo, my error message: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: file://C:\Xiang\cs_hdfs\csByDate\20190822/C:/Xiang/323Bit/bigfoot, expected: file:///
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:645)

 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.pathToFile(RawLocalFileSystem.java:80)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:534)
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:752)`

Comment: I’m afraid that I don’t have Windows computer.

Comment: How could I check whether a Hadoop environment is set in the Java code?

Answer (score 26):

gonbe's answer is excellent. But still I want to mention that `file:///` = `~/../../`, not `$SPARK_HOME`. Hope this could save some time for newbs like me.

Comment: `file:///` is the root folder of the filesystem as seen by the executing JVM, not two levels above the home folder. The URI format as specified in [RFC 8089](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8089) is `file://hostname/absolute/path`. In the local case the `hostname` (authority) component is empty.

Answer (score 22):

If the file is located in your Spark master node (e.g., in case of using AWS EMR), then launch the spark-shell in local mode first.

```
$ spark-shell --master=local
scala> val df = spark.read.json("file:///usr/lib/spark/examples/src/main/resources/people.json")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [age: bigint, name: string]

scala> df.show()
+----+-------+
| age|   name|
+----+-------+
|null|Michael|
|  30|   Andy|
|  19| Justin|
+----+-------+
```

Alternatively, you can first copy the file to HDFS from the local file system and then launch Spark in its default mode (e.g., YARN in case of using AWS EMR) to read the file directly.

```
$ hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /hdfs/spark/examples
$ hadoop fs -put /usr/lib/spark/examples/src/main/resources/people.json /hdfs/spark/examples
$ hadoop fs -ls /hdfs/spark/examples
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   1 hadoop hadoop         73 2017-05-01 00:49 /hdfs/spark/examples/people.json

$ spark-shell
scala> val df = spark.read.json("/hdfs/spark/examples/people.json")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [age: bigint, name: string]

scala> df.show()
+----+-------+
| age|   name|
+----+-------+
|null|Michael|
|  30|   Andy|
|  19| Justin|
+----+-------+
```

Comment: The only answer that tells and shows you how to start in local mode. This one needs more upvotes.

Answer (score 22):

While Spark supports loading files from the local filesystem, it requires that the files are available at the same path on all nodes in your cluster.

Some network filesystems, like NFS, AFS, and MapR’s NFS layer, are exposed to the user as a regular filesystem.

If your data is already in one of these systems, then you can use it as an input by just specifying a *file://* path; Spark will handle it as long as the filesystem is mounted at the same path on each node. Every node needs to have the same path

```
 rdd = sc.textFile("file:///path/to/file")
```

If your file isn’t already on all nodes in the cluster, you can load it locally on the driver without going through Spark and then call parallelize to distribute the contents to workers

Take care to put file:// in front and the use of "/" or "\" according to OS.

Comment: Is there a way that Spark will automatically copy data from its $SPARK_HOME directory to all computing nodes. Or do you need to do that manually?

Comment: where is the spark source code handling different file system formats?

Answer (score 19):

**Attention:**

Make sure that you run spark in local mode when you load data from  local(`sc.textFile("file:///path to the file/")`) or you will get error like this `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/data/sparkjob/config2.properties does not exist`.
Becasuse executors which run on different workers will not find this file in it's local path.

Comment: Can we run spark standalone mode (driver on one node, executors on other nodes) on a local file in the driver? Or should I have the local file present on all the nodes?

Answer (score 14):

You need just to specify the path of the file as **"file:///directory/file"**

example:

```
val textFile = sc.textFile("file:///usr/local/spark/README.md")
```

Answer (score 10):

I have a file called NewsArticle.txt on my Desktop.

In Spark, I typed:

```
val textFile= sc.textFile(“file:///C:/Users/582767/Desktop/NewsArticle.txt”)
```

I needed to change all the \ to / character for the filepath.

To test if it worked, I typed:

```
textFile.foreach(println)
```

I'm running Windows 7 and I don't have Hadoop installed.

Answer (score 6):

This has happened to me with Spark 2.3 with Hadoop also installed under the common "hadoop" user home directory.Since both Spark and Hadoop was installed under the same common directory, Spark by default considers the scheme as `hdfs`, and starts looking for the input files under hdfs as specified by `fs.defaultFS` in Hadoop's `core-site.xml`. Under such cases, we need to explicitly specify the scheme as `file:///<absoloute path to file>`.

Answer (score 5):

This has been discussed into spark mailing list, and please refer this [mail](http://mail-archives.us.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201402.mbox/%3C0305B4C9-4B0C-4C29-82E9-A38B03BF1A13@gmail.com%3E).

You should use `hadoop fs -put <localsrc> ... <dst>` copy the file into `hdfs`:

```
${HADOOP_COMMON_HOME}/bin/hadoop fs -put /path/to/README.md README.md
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following and it worked from my local file system.. Basically spark can read from local, HDFS and AWS S3 path

```
listrdd=sc.textFile("file:////home/cloudera/Downloads/master-data/retail_db/products")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for this error that i was getting on Spark cluster that is hosted in Azure on a windows cluster:

Load the raw HVAC.csv file, parse it using the function

```
data = sc.textFile("wasb:///HdiSamples/SensorSampleData/hvac/HVAC.csv")
```

We use (wasb:///) to allow Hadoop to access azure blog storage file and the three slashes is a relative reference to the running node container folder.

For example: If the path for your file in File Explorer in Spark cluster dashboard is:

sflcc1\sflccspark1\HdiSamples\SensorSampleData\hvac

So to describe the path is as follows: sflcc1: is the name of the storage account. sflccspark: is the cluster node name.

So we refer to the current cluster node name with the relative three slashes.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to read file form HDFS. trying setting path in SparkConf

```
 val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("HDFSFileReader")
 conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://hostname:9000")
```

Comment: Please add 4-space/tab indentation to your code so that it gets formatted as code. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use sc.textFile(...) to convert local files into dataframes. One of options is, to read a local file line by line and then transform it into Spark Dataset. Here is an example for Windows machine in Java:

```
StructType schemata = DataTypes.createStructType(
            new StructField[]{
                    createStructField("COL1", StringType, false),
                    createStructField("COL2", StringType, false),
                    ...
            }
    );

String separator = ";";
String filePath = "C:\\work\\myProj\\myFile.csv";
SparkContext sparkContext = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("MyApp").setMaster("local"));
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext (sparkContext );
SQLContext sqlContext = SQLContext.getOrCreate(sparkContext );

List<String[]> result = new ArrayList<>();
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      String[] vals = line.split(separator);
      result.add(vals);
    }
 } catch (Exception ex) {
       System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
       throw new RuntimeException(ex);
  }
  JavaRDD<String[]> jRdd = jsc.parallelize(result);
  JavaRDD<Row> jRowRdd = jRdd .map(RowFactory::create);
  Dataset<Row> data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(jRowRdd, schemata);
```

Now you can use dataframe `data` in your code.

Answer (score -1):

Reading local file in Apache-Spark. This worked for me:

```
var a = sc.textFile("/home/omkar/Documents/text_input").flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1));
```

Answer (score -7):

try

```
val f = sc.textFile("./README.md")
```

Comment: `scala> val f = sc.textFile("./README.md")
14/12/04 12:54:33 INFO storage.MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(81443) called with curMem=164073, maxMem=278302556
14/12/04 12:54:33 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 79.5 KB, free 265.2 MB)
f: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ./README.md MappedRDD[5] at textFile at <console>:12

scala> val wc = f.flatMap(l => l.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://sandbox:9000/user/root/README.md
 at`

Comment: Can you do a `pwd` on the bash shell `bash-4.1#`

Comment: bash-4.1# pwd
/usr/local/spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4

Comment: This works for me on spark without hadoop/hdfs.  However, it doesn't seem to be working for the OP, as it gave them an error dump.