# Load a local file to spark using sc.textFile()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, rdd

## Question

How to load a file from the local file system to Spark using sc.textFile? Do I need to change any `-env` variables? Also when I tried the same on my windows where  Hadoop is not installed I got the same error.

## Code

```
> val inputFile = sc.textFile("file///C:/Users/swaapnika/Desktop/to do list")
/17 22:28:18 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(63280) called with curMem=0, maxMem=278019440
/17 22:28:18 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 61.8 KB, free 265.1 MB)
/17 22:28:18 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(19750) called with curMem=63280, maxMem=278019440
/17 22:28:18 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 19.3 KB, free 265.1 MB)
/17 22:28:18 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on localhost:53659 (size: 19.3 KB, free: 265.1 MB)
/17 22:28:18 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from textFile at <console>:21
File: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:21

> val words = input.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
ole>:19: error: not found: value input
  val words = input.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
              ^

> val words = inputFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[2] at flatMap at <console>:23

> val counts = words.map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey{case (x, y) => x + y}
```

## Error

```
apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/c:/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/file/C:/Users/swaapnika/Desktop/to do list
   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:285)
   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:228)
   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:313)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:207)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
   at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
   at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
   at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
   at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
   at org.apache.spark.Partitioner$.defaultPartitioner(Partitioner.scala:65)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$reduceByKey$3.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:290)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$reduceByKey$3.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:290)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:286)
   at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.reduceByKey(PairRDDFunctions.scala:289)
   at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:25)
   at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:30)
   at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:32)
   at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:34)
   at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:36)
   at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:38)
   at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:40)
   at $iwC.<init>(<console>:42)
   at <init>(<console>:44)
   at .<init>(<console>:48)
   at .<clinit>(<console>)
   at .<init>(<console>:7)
   at .<clinit>(<console>)
   at $print(<console>)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
   at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
   at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1338)
   at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
   at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
   at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
   at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
   at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
   at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
   at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
   at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
   at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
   at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
   at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
   at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
   at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
   at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
   at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
   at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
   at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
   at 

org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:665)
   at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:170)
   at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:193)
   at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:112)
   at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)


>
```

Comment: you can read similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27299923/how-to-load-local-file-in-sc-textfile-instead-of-hdfs

Answer (score 0):

I checked all the dependencies and the environment variables again. 
The actual path "file:///home/..../.. .txt" would fetch the data from the local file system as the hadoop env.sh file has its default file system set to fs.defaultFs.
If we leave the Spark-env.sh to its defaults without any change it takes the local file system when it encounters "file://..." and the hdfs when the path is "hdfs://.." 
If you specifically need any file system export HADOOP_CONF_DIR to the spark-env.sh
And it would support any file system supported by Hadoop.
This was my observation. Any corrections or suggestions accepted. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
val inputFile = sc.textFile("file///C:/Users/swaapnika/Desktop/to do list")
```

to this:

```
val inputFile = sc.textFile("file:///Users/swaapnika/Desktop/to do list")
```

I'm also fairly new to hadoop and spark, but from what I gather, when running spark locally on Windows, the string `file:///` when passed to `sc.textFile` already refers to `C:\`.

Comment: yes I think that might be a typo but even the latter gave me the same error.The thing we could do is set the set the hadoop and spark dependencies right when there is already a running hadoop version.The defaultFS. Else set it in the Hadoop_conf_DIR

Answer (score 0):

The file path you have defined is incorrect.

Try changing

```
sc.textFile("file///C:/Users/swaapnika/Desktop/to do list")
```

to

```
sc.textFile("file://C:/Users/swaapnika/Desktop/to do list")
```

or

```
sc.textFile("C:/Users/swaapnika/Desktop/to do list")
```

Comment: yes I think that might be a typo but even the latter gave me the same error.The thing we could do is set the set the hadoop and spark dependencies right when there is already a running hadoop version.The defaultFS. Else set it in the Hadoop_conf_DIR .Thanks Jem

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when you run spark in a cluster. When you submit a job to spark cluster the cluster manager(YARN or Mesos or any) will submit it to worker node. When the worker node trying to find the path of the file we need to load into spark it fails because the worker doesn't have such file. So try running spark-shell in local mode and try again,

`\bin\spark-shell --master local`

`sc.textFile("file:///C:/Users/swaapnika/Desktop/to do list")`

let me know if this helps.

Comment: can you post me the error your facing? and the command you used to start spark shell?