# How to read the file stored in cloudera home folder

Tags: python, apache-spark, cloudera, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I am new to python and spark and i have installed cloudera quickstart and I am trying to read a file which i created in cloudera's home folder which is present in the cloudera distribution desktop, how can i read the file?

I tried using the below command to read the file

```
lines = sc.textFile("file:///home/cloudera/data/testfile.csv")
```

Is there any specific format in which the command needs to be written or should I store the file in some other  place.

Am I missing something here.

Comment: read similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27299923/how-to-load-local-file-in-sc-textfile-instead-of-hdfs

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: I wonder what is the error too.  The common error can be permission or wrong path