# The function passed to map never gets called

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to make a function call through the `map` function available in spark.
I did what was given in the spark tutorial page (https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/programming-guide.html). But the function `myFunc` never gets called. At least that's what I think. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or missing out something.
This is the following code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
if __name__ == "__main__":
    def myFunc(s):
        print("@@")
        words = s.split("\n")
        print("##")
        return len(words)


    sc = SparkContext("local","test")
    sc.textFile("C:\\TestLogs\\sample.log").map(myFunc)
    print("**")
```

Output:

```
**
```

In fact, this is the same example from the spark doc except for the file location.

Comment: I don't know Python, but you defined your function with a parameter (s). When you call it, you are not passing any argument. Are you sure that's ok?

Comment: @kaks I don't know Spark, but map over something _empty_ won't call a function even once. Can you confirm your file actually provide any data?

Comment: @facundop : Yes it has a parameter. But in the spark docs, in map, `myFunc` doesn't take a parameter even though function is defined with `s`.
@ŁukaszRogalski :  Yes the sample.log file has 10 log lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your code lacks spark "action" (e.g. "collect") which is required in order to execute the transformations (e.g. "map").

Try the following:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
if __name__ == "__main__":
    def myFunc(s):
        print("@@")
        words = s.split("\n")
        print("##")
        return len(words)


    sc = SparkContext("local","test")
    myrdd = sc.textFile("C:\\TestLogs\\sample.log")
    result =  myrdd.map(myFunc).collect()
    print "the result is"
    print result
    print("**")
```

consider updating the following to hold "file:\\" (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27301040/5088142)

```
    myrdd = sc.textFile("file:\\C:\\TestLogs\\sample.log")
```

Answer (score 1):

IT seems like you have **not called action just** transformation `map(myFunc)`.

> All transformations in Spark **are lazy**, in that they do not compute
>   their results right away. Instead, they just **remember the
>   transformations** applied to some base dataset (e.g. a file). The
>   transformations are only **computed when an action requires** a result to
>   be returned to the driver program.

Try to use `map(myFunc).saveAsTextFile("folder/here.txt")` or some other [action](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#actions) you would like to use.