# How to load local file using sc.textFile in spark?

Tags: scala, file, apache-spark

I've been trying to load local file using `sc.textFile()`in spark.

I already read [question]:[How to load local file in sc.textFile, instead of HDFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27299923/how-to-load-local-file-in-sc-textfile-instead-of-hdfs)

I have local file in `/home/spark/data.txt` on Centos 7.0

When I use `val data = sc.textFile("file:///home/spark/data.txt").collect`, I got a error as below.

> 16/12/27 12:15:56 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID
>   36,): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/spark/data.txt does not
>   exist
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:609)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:822)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:599)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:421)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.(ChecksumFileSystem.java:140)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:341)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:767)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.(LineRecordReader.java:109)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.(HadoopRDD.scala:246)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:209)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:102)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
>           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> 16/12/27 12:15:56 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 4
>   times; aborting job org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due
>   to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 5.0 failed 4 times, most recent
>   failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 5.0 (TID 42,):
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/spark/data.txt does not exist
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:609)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:822)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:599)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:421)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.(ChecksumFileSystem.java:140)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:341)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:767)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.(LineRecordReader.java:109)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.(HadoopRDD.scala:246)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:209)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:102)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)
>           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Driver stacktrace:   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1438)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
>   at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>   at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48) 
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
>   at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1659)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1618)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1607)
>   at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
>   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1871)   at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1884)   at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1897)   at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1911)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:893)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:892)   ... 48 elided Caused
>   by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/spark/data.txt does not exist 
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:609)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:822)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:599)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:421)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.(ChecksumFileSystem.java:140)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:341)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:767)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LineRecordReader.(LineRecordReader.java:109)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.getRecordReader(TextInputFormat.java:67)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.(HadoopRDD.scala:246) 
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:209)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:102)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
>   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:85)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274) 
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Apparently there is a file in this path. If I use wrong path, then the error is like below.

```
 val data = sc.textFile("file:///data.txt").collect
```

> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not
>   exist: file:/data.txt   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:287)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:200)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:248)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:246)
>   at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:246)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:248)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:246)
>   at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:246)   at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1911)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:893)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:892)

I don't know why it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am stuck in a similar issue and banging my head from past 2 hours. I have a file on my local unix dir and spark is running on different machine. I am also getting a file not found exception.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you.

I've been also still getting a file not found exception.

Comment: One thing that I figured out is if your spark server and the server on which file is are different then you cannot directly use the `sc.textFile`. You will have to put the file first into hdfs then you can use it. I just tried that and it worked.

Comment: That's good! 
I already put the file into hdfs but It's not worked...

Answer (score 1):

copy that file to your $SPARK_HOME folder and use this command:`val data = sc.textFile("data.txt").collect`

Answer (score 0):

use this `val data = sc.textFile("/home/spark/data.txt")` this should work
and set master as local.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I usually use HDFS, but sometimes I have to load local file. 
So I  tried to use `file:///PATH` to load local file.

Comment: The answer is No.
If I just use `sc.textFile()` without `file:///`, it does not work. 
Because the default path is set HDFS.

Comment: `file:///` should work only if you are running in cluster. to access a file from local machine set master as local and then run.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 
I'll try it! Have a nice day~

Answer (score 0):

Your data file needs to exist in 'home/spark/data.txt' on ALL executer nodes.I know it's kind of preposterous. To fix it, you have the following options:

1. Move the data file to HDFS
2. Copy the data file on all the executer nodes
3. Load the file in pure Scala (not Spark) and then use sc.parallelize() to create the RDDs.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is our local is different from spark local. so when you run your pyspark, it's mandatory to mention your code must be run in your local machine, especially when you use AWS EC2. So simply run 
  ./pyspark --master local[n]
after that your local and spark local will be the same.....
don't forget to use(file:///....)