# How to load a local file with a local spark session

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm running a local spark session on my mac via my intellij sbt console and I get a 
`org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file:/Users/myuser/Documents/data/dataset.csv;` error.

my current code looks like this:
`val data = spark.read.csv("file:///Users/myuser/Documents/data/dataset.csv")`

I've also tried:

`val data = spark.read.csv("/Users/myuser/Documents/data/dataset.csv")`

my spark session looks like this

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

trait SparkSessionWrapper {

  lazy val spark: SparkSession = {
    SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("avro_test")
      .getOrCreate()
  }

}
```

I know this is the same issue as the one found here:  [How to load local file in sc.textFile, instead of HDFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27299923/how-to-load-local-file-in-sc-textfile-instead-of-hdfs?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

but none of the answers here (and others i've looked at) are helping me or else i'm not fully understanding them.  any suggestions?

Comment: also i'm using spark 2.2.0

Comment: Nothing wrong with the `SparkSession`. It has been created correctly. Are you sure that path you had mentioned indeed exists in your machine?

Comment: Your right! there was a error in my path and that was it, How embarrassing.  thank you