# How to read text file which is located in server using sc.textfile("") method in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have logged in to `ma1-dsrqt-lapp101.corp.apple.com` server
inside the server file location is (Note : this file is not there in HDFS Location)
`/ngs/app/idmaerqt/reports/BD_REPORTS_RK/missingRecs.txt`

I am trying to read this file with below code using spark 1.6.2 but not able to read the file.

```
val inputPath = "/ngs/app/idmaerqt/reports/BD_REPORTS_RK/missingRecs.txt"
inputRecords = sc.textFile("file:///"+inputPath)
```

Please let me know where I am doing wrong, any help appreciated.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: [How to load local file in sc.textFile, instead of HDFS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27299923/10465355) in particular [Aklank Jain answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47631339/10465355) - _While Spark supports loading files from the local filesystem, it requires that the files are available at the same path on all nodes in your cluster_

Comment: I am using the same approach but still getting the same issue, can you please elaborate thanks

Comment: @Krishna if the file is small enough, you may read it with normal Scala code, and turn it into a local **Seq** which then you can convert to an **RDD** / **DataFrame** / **Dataset** `Source.fromFile(path).getLines().toDF` - however, this is only for a development / testing perspective, in production prefer always **HDFS** or **S3** or other kind of distributed filesytem.