# Why do Apache Spark nodes need access to datafile path?

Tags: apache-spark

I am new to Apache Spark.
I have a cluster with a master and one worker. I am connected to master with pyspark (all are on Ubuntu VM).

I am reading this documentation: [RDD external-datasets](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/rdd-programming-guide.html#external-datasets)

in particular I have executed:

```
distFile = sc.textFile("data.txt")
```

I understand that this creates an RDD from file, which should be managed by the driver, hence by pyspark app.
But the doc states:

> If using a path on the local filesystem, the file must also be accessible at the same path on worker nodes. Either copy the file to all workers or use a network-mounted shared file system.

Question is why do workers need access to the file path if the RDD is created by the driver only (afterwards distributed to the nodes)?

Comment: Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27299923/how-to-load-local-file-in-sc-textfile-instead-of-hdfs

Comment: thanks @thebluephantom. I understand that is required to have the file on all nodes but I do not understand why.

Comment: Well neither do I but it is not a typical real life approach to big data.